# ROS Answers SE migration: New to ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to go through tutorial to create a new package in current directory which is i think ROS, but getting following mistake,can someone help me out in this

```
shailendraparihar@ubuntu:/opt/ros/electric/ros$ roscreate-pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/roscreate-pkg", line 35, in <module>
    roscreate.roscreatepkg.roscreatepkg_main()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/roscreate/src/roscreate/roscreatepkg.py", line 126, in roscreatepkg_main
    create_package(package, author_name(), depends, uses_roscpp=uses_roscpp, uses_rospy=uses_rospy)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/tools/roscreate/src/roscreate/roscreatepkg.py", line 63, in create_package
    os.makedirs(p)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/ros/electric/ros/beginner_tutorials'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34786/new-to-ros./) by [srj0408](https://answers.ros.org/users/2314/srj0408/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not create any files in /opt/ros. Instead, you should set up an overlay in your home directory. Have a look at [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment) tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2